# RDLC report not reflecting any design changes after edit

Tags: c#, .net, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a RDLC report which I designed some time ago. Problem is that I have changed the design (like logo change), but whenever I run the report it shows old logo. It shows my old report as it is at runtime.

Comment: try changing other stuff and check maybe cache issue. or you have put a condition

Comment: Thanks i tried what you have just said and it worked ..!! . I am so dumb :). Thanks again.